# What's the default unit of length for lines draw with 3D coordinates in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, units, draw

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0) node [midway,below] {2D (1)};
\draw (0, -1) -- (1cm, -1) node [midway,below] {2D (1 cm)};
\draw (0, -2, 0) -- (1, -2, 0) node [midway,below] {3D (1)};
\draw (0, -3, 0) -- (1cm, -3, 0) node [midway,below] {3D (1cm)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I was expecting the 3rd line and 4th line to be of equal length because I thought the default unit of the length in `\draw` command is `cm`.

Why is the 4th line longer than the 3rd line? In fact, the 4th line goes all the way to the right edge of the generated PDF output.

Answer (score 11):

Confer the manual, section 13.2.1 *Canvas, XYZ, and Polar Coordinate Systems*.

When you do `(1,0)`, the `xyz` coordinate system is used. In this coordinate system, the numbers given are factors multiplied by the default unit vectors, which are (1cm, 0), (0, 1cm) and (-3.85mm, -3.85mm), for x, y and z respectively. The numbers are passed through the math parser, so you can do `(1+2,0)`, and this is the same as `(3,0)`.

When you do `(1cm,0)`, the `canvas` coordinate system is used, in which a specific dimension is supplied. So here, the values are not multiplied by the unit vectors. (If you mix dimensions and scalars, the `pt` unit is assumed for the scalars, so `(1+2cm,0)` is *not* the same as `(1+2,0)`, because it becomes `1pt+2cm`.)

But when you specify three components, `(x,y,z)`, you always get the `xyz` coordinate system. So the numbers are parsed by the math parser, before multiplication with the unit vector. And if you do `\pgfmathparse{1cm}\pgfmathresult`, you get `28.45274`, because `pt` is the "base" unit, and other lengths are converted to `pt`. The fourth of your lines is about 28.453 cm long, because, when you do `(1cm,0,0)`, the x-component ends up as `28.45274 × (1cm,0)`.

A simpler example to see this behaviour, is below, which gives two lines of the same length.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0,0)    -- (2pt,0,0);
\draw (0,-0.5,0) -- (2,-0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is an example of calculating the line length in cm. Note I used 1mm instead of 1cm in the xyz-coordinate:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1mm,0,0);
\draw
let
\p1=(a),\p2=(b),
% length of line in centimetres
% \x1,\x2 in pt, 72.27pt per inch, 2.54cm per inch
\n1={scalar((\x2-\x1)*2.54/72.27)}
in
(a) -- node [above] {\n1\,cm} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```